# cffile not working at all

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

[image]cffile is giving a head ache now.
 My cfm is like this -

`

```
<cfif session.ismac and session.browsermake eq "firefox">
<cfset size = "55">
</cfif> 
<cfset onChange = "document.frmMain.submit1.disabled = true;setdisplayname(this,this.form.dummy);">
<cfif displayname EQ "">
<cfset size = "document.frmMain.submit1.disabled = true;setdisplayname(this,this.form.displayname);">
</cfif> 


<cfinput type="file" name="File#thisUploader#" id="File#thisUploader#" size="#size#" onKeyPress="return false;" onchange="#onChange#">
```

`

and in my cfc the code is like this -

```
<cffile accept="image/*" action="upload" destination="#application.artworkfilepath#\bulkuploads\#session.loginname#\#form.category#\" filefield="form.File#thisUploader#" nameconflict="makeunique">
```

and if I dump - `<cfoutput> 
    You uploaded #cffile.ClientFileName#.#cffile.ClientFileExt# 
    successfully to #cffile.ServerDirectory#.
</cfoutput> 
<cfabort>`

I get corrct things and no error.
But when i look into the folder there is nothing.

Anyidea? I have added the dump of cffile now. What do you make out of it?
 cfform code is like this `<cfform id="frmMain" name="frmMain" action="process_multi.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_self" method="post">`

Comment: Have you dumped the entire cffile struct after <cffile action="upload"... /> ? That might provide some useful info, maybe post the content here if it doesn't give you the answer.

Comment: You say "in my cfc the code is like this". Are you posting to a .cfm that calls a CFC containing that line of code? Can you post the rest of the code for that function in your cfc? Also, can you post you <cfform> code as well?

Comment: sorry it is a cfm that i m posting to not a cfc.

Comment: Can you post you <cfform> code as well?

Answer (score 0):

do a fileExists() directly after the statement and let us know what that says...

you don't have a directorywatcher on the directory do you?

Answer (score 0):

Your cffile `nameconfict` attribute is set to `makeunique`, which tells ColdFusion to rename the file to something new when it arrives at the server--if the file already exists.

However, you are using `cffile.ClientFileName` and `cffile.ClientFileExt` to refer to the file file--which maps to the unchanged file name as it was received during upload.

Change your code references to `cffile.ServerFileName` and `cffile.ServerFileExt` for the final renamed result.